# как сделать кружки в placeholder

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать круги в placeholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - использование кастомного шрифта `font-family: 'pass';`

Пример

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'pass';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff');
}

input[type=password] {
  font-family: 'pass', 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0 .75rem;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=password]:placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="•••••••">
```

Comment: А зачем кастомный шрифт? Не достаточно просто `placeholder="•••••••"`?

Comment: @another_login для сравнения https://jsfiddle.net/szmqw6xo/1/

Comment: спасибо, наглядно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы точно уверены, что вам это надо ? Обычно дизайнеры условно показывают что это поле пароля, (`<input id="pass" type="password">`) и на реальных проектах таким никто не занимается, поскольку отображение данного поля зависит от того каким браузером пользуется пользователь.
Если это принципиально важно, то тут только через JS который будет отслеживать введенное количество знаков и визуально отображать эти "кружки", Но там появиться масса других проблем после этого.